# Effective methods for this qustion.

Tags: contest-math, puzzle

In the beginning, the numbers $1, 2, 3, ..., 57$ were written on the board. In each process, the numbers a and b are selected and deleted from the board so that the number $a$ divides the number $b$ completely. The number $\frac{b}{a}$ is written instead of the deleted numbers (For example, in the first operation, the numbers $a = 3$ and $b = 9$ can be deleted and the number $\frac{9}{3} = 3$ can be written on the board again). At least how many numbers can be left on the board after a few actions?

It is clear that  the remaining numbers are primes $29,31,37,41,43,47,53$.
In each of my attempts, I find $2$ different numbers in addition to these prime.  But I am waiting for your answers to see more different points of view.

Comment: I'm getting atleast $12$ primes left over. Can you explain why $17$ is not remaining, its multiples are $17, 34,51$?

Comment: I  removed all x and and 2x such that $x$ is not a prime. Then $1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,27,29,31,33,34,35,37,38,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55$ are the remaining numbers. I reduced  these numbers.  For your question,  $2.17=34$, $3.17=51$. Remove $51$ and $3$, then remove $17$ and $34$.

Comment: $\{17,34,51\}$. $51/3=17$. We have $\{17,17,34\}$. $34/17=2$. We have $17$ and $2$. One $17$ is remaining, no? Since b/a is written in place of deleted numbers.

Comment: I think we dont write again $17$, because it is in board.

Comment: @cosmo5 I agree with you that 17 or 34 or 51 must be left over.

Comment: @CalvinLin That's how I saw but it seems OP is interpreting the question in a different way.

Comment: Maybe, I am wrong I dont know :D

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I disagree with "I think we dont write again 17, because it is in board". That isn't stated in the question, and it's often not in the rules of similar questions. You write whatever number you've left with after following the rules, even if it results in duplicates.

Comment: @CalvinLin You look right :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain what you've tried.)

**Hint:** Consider the prime factorization of $ 57! $.
Focus on those whose power is odd.
As you've realized, the primes $> 28$ must always occur. These have power of 1 in the prime factorization.

---

**Claim:** The product of the numbers that are left can be written in the form $ \frac{ \prod_{a \in A } a } { \prod_{b \not \in A } b } $, where $ A \subset [57]$.

**Claim:** If $p ^k \mid \mid 57$ and $k$ is odd, then we're always left with a term that is a multiple of $p$.

**Corollary:** The product of the numbers at the end is

> $$ 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 17 \times 19 \times 29 \times 31 \times 37 \times 41 \times 43 \times 47 \times 53.$$

**Corollary:** We must have at least $X$ numbers left behind. Recall that each of these numbers is less than 57.

> $X = 11$

**Corollary:** The minimum left behind is $X$, and we need to find a contraction that yields $X$.

(Disclaimer: I've not done this yet.)

> One possible set of numbers to be left is $ 7, 38, 55, 57, 29 , 31 ,37 , 41 , 43 , 47 , 53$.
>  We do not use any of these in the steps, other than possibly 7.
>  However, thinking through it further, because "b/a is an integer" is a very strong condition, the invariant might be too weak. So, this part is worth thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

You might try an approach like this in EXCEL because you don't have to worry about word-wrap, and you can see the entire string if the cells to the right are empty.

Beginning with $\{1,2,3,\cdots,57\}\\$

\begin{align*}
Column_A\quad & Column_B\\
19,57\rightarrow3\quad &\{1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7\cdots 56\}\\
8,56\rightarrow7\quad &\{1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7\cdots 55\}\\
11,55\rightarrow5\quad &\{1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7\cdots 54\}\\
27,54\rightarrow2\quad &\{1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
\end{align*}

Now, perhaps it is time to cleanup such as

\begin{align*}
2,2\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,1,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
3,3\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,7,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
5,5\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,1,1,4,6,7,7,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
7,7\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,1,1,1,4,6,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
1,1\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,1,1,4,6,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
1,1\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,1,4,6,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
1,1\rightarrow1\quad &\{1,4,6,\cdots,26,28\cdots 53\}\\
13,52\rightarrow4\quad &\{1,4,4,6,\cdots,12,14\cdots,26,28\cdots,51,53\}\\
\end{align*}

Number will be deleted, added, and deleted again from the list. For example, the interactions of $\quad11,55\quad 4,44 \quad 11,33 \quad 2,22\quad 11,11\quad$ will end up deleting $11$ from the list permanently. As an alternative to the above, you can, in one step, drop the numbers $\quad 11,22,33,44,55\quad$ from the list, knowing $11$ and multiples will all go. For other "factors" you will have to test them for having odd or even interactions as we did with $11x$.